# Issue with PL/SQL Output

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I created this procedure in Oracle SQL Developer.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CUST_NAME_LIMIT(
I_CUSTOMER_NUM IN CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NUM%TYPE,
I_CUSTOMER_NAME OUT CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NAME%TYPE,
I_CREDIT_LIMIT OUT CUSTOMER.CREDIT_LIMIT%TYPE)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT CUSTOMER_NAME, CREDIT_LIMIT
INTO
I_CUSTOMER_NAME, I_CREDIT_LIMIT
FROM
CUSTOMER
WHERE
CUSTOMER_NAME = I_CUSTOMER_NAME;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(I_CUSTOMER_NAME);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(I_CREDIT_LIMIT);
END;
```

When I try to display the output with this below I get an error

```
BEGIN
CUST_NAME_LIMIT('126');
END;
```

It should out put 
TOYS GALORE
7500

Comment: *an error*? And the issue is with the output, not with the procedure logic? Is `customer_name` defined as unique, by the way? http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Answer (score 0):

Only if you told us *which* error you got, instead of letting us guess. But hey, it is more fun this way!

As you declared a procedure to accept one `IN` and two `OUT` parameters:

```
create or replace procedure cust_name_limit(
  i_customer_num in customer.customer_num%type,
  i_customer_name out customer.customer_name%type,
  i_credit_limit out customer.credit_limit%type)
as
begin
  select customer_name, credit_limit
  into i_customer_name, i_credit_limit
  from customer
  where customer_name = i_customer_name;
end;
```

you have to do the same when calling it:

```
declare
  l_custname customer.customer_name%type;
  l_credlim  customer.credit_limit%type;
begin
  CUST_NAME_LIMIT('126', l_custname, l_credlim);

  dbms_output.put_line(l_custname ||' - '|| l_credlim);
end;
/
```

Displaying the result from within the procedure doesn't make much sense; do so once it returns values.